# Can't enable http traffic on instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, hortonworks-data-platform

When I use [these instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/platforms/hdp/README.md) to create a Hadoop cluster, "Allow http traffic" is grayed out in the console, which prevents me from accessing Ambari. Is there any way I can enable it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I know you already solved your problem, but please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27749183/3618671) as to how and why you should use a SOCKS proxy instead of opening up an HTTP port to Ambari directly. See also https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely for a more complete howto doc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In this case, I am using for a course (which will hopefully be publicly available at some point), so I'm not sure I need a SOCKS proxy. However, even after opening for http traffic, I still needed to use a SOCKS proxy to access Ambari (not sure why), so opening http didn't really solve my problem...

Comment: The built-in HTTP firewall rule opens up port 80, and the built-in HTTPS firewall rule opens up port 443 because those are the ports such services run on. Ambari web UI runs on a different port (8080) so you would need a custom firewall rule to open that specific port. That said, I would still not recommend serving Ambari UI over HTTP because of the reasons in the above post.

Comment: Understood. Still, I can't view it even when I open port 8080. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I get where you're coming from, but it is really painful to say everyone in the class has to setup a SOCKS proxy as there is no private data on the server...

Comment: There are two firewalls: (1) on the VM (the OS has a firewall blocks most ports except SSH), and (2) on GCE. You have to open each port on both, or (insecure) disable the OS firewall and open a few ports in the GCE firewall. There are more issues, however: Hadoop will cross-link from the UI to other servers, e.g., for job status but will use internal `10.x.y.z` IPs which aren't accessible via the Internet, and on other ports; thus inaccessible without a SOCKS proxy. It's quite simple to run `bdutil socksproxy` (in the doc you linked to) and then configure the browser to use it.

Answer (score 29):

Embarrassingly simple but I'll put in an answer in case anyone is as dumb as me. Hit the "edit" button and then you can change it :/

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Comment: Not dumb at all. what is dumb is the need to click edit

Comment: Haha this is great! Thanks.

Comment: Haha. Typical Google UX